# Who is the great prophet in Luke 7:16?

Tags: catholicism, luke

In Luke 7:16, after Jesus raised the widow's son his disciples and the crowd said:

> They were all filled with awe and praised God. “A great prophet has
>   appeared among us,” they said.

Who is the great prophet mentioned here? Was it Jesus?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Of course they're talking about Jesus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people - not yet recognizing that Jesus is God - call Him a prophet immediately after witnessing the raising of the son of the widow at Nain.

If this is not completely obvious from Luke 17:11-16, it may be more clear from the text which follows.  Luke writes that *This rumor* [i.e. *that a great prophet is risen among us*] *of Him went forth throughout all Judaea, and throughout all the region round about*.  This is what the Pharisee who criticized Jesus to himself had in mind when the woman anointed His feet with her tears:  *This man, if he were a prophet, would have known who and what manner of woman this is that toucheth Him: for she is a sinner* (v.39).

Comment: Note that even with Him being God, He's still *also* a prophet (and High Priest and King and a dozen other roles and ministries), so the people didn't make a mistake by calling Him a prophet, they just didn't know He was *more* than that. It fact, Jesus even twice implicitly but pretty clearly calls *Himself* a prophet, both when He says "One greater than Moses is here", and when He says, "A prophet is not without honor except in his own town/house" (paraphrasing from memory).

Comment: It seems to me that "not yet recognizing that Jesus was the Messiah" might be more accurate that "not yet recognizing that Jesus is  God" but that's your call on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The great prophet they were referring to was Jesus. Deuteronomy 18:15-18 speaks of a prophet greater than Moses whom the people shall listen to. This is likely what Luke is referencing to when he quoted the words of the people who witnessed the miracle.

Comment: so he is not God?

Comment: I didn't say that and won't interpret on what I think regarding Jesus' divinity. Just realize that the gospels do refer to Jesus as a prophet. Cleopas says to Jesus while not realizing it's him, "Concerning Jesus of Nazareth, a man who was a prophet mighty in deed and word before God and all the people, and how our chief priests and rulers delivered him up to be condemned to death, and crucified him." (Luke 24:19, 20)

Comment: A prophet is someone who proclaims God's will and teaches of things to come. So yes, Prophet is one of many titles appropriate for Jesus Christ, the Son of God.

Comment: @Casanova Being a great prophet and being God are not mutually exclusive. Jesus is both. For example, John 12:49 says, "*For I did not speak on My own initiative, but the Father Himself who sent Me has given Me a commandment as to what to say and what to speak.*", which is very similar to say, Isaiah or Moses or other prophets. Also, both Prophet and Teacher are among the five-fold ministries, and being a Teacher does not exclude divinity either. Jesus is also the Shepard/pastor of the Church. That doesn't exclude divinity. Nor does being King or even being the **High Priest**.

Comment: @JaminGrey so we have two Gods here then?

Comment: No, a triune God. Three persons in one being - the Trinity. =)
Irregardless, even if God was purely one person, what precisely prevents Him from being a Teacher? Or a Judge? Or a King? Or a Pastor? You are seeming to have difficulty with God engaging in prophetic ministry - In your view, what precisely about being a prophet is incompatible with Jesus' ministry or nature? Or do you think being divine is incompatible with Jesus' ministry or nature?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to be dismissive - you ask good questions, and the Bible is meant to be questioned - I just am trying to understand what conflict you see, so we can get on the same page. =P

Comment: A prophet is a person which is inspired by God. This doesn't make him God

Comment: You are using a false dichotomy, @Casanova.  The gospel reports what people were saying (it helps to stop cherry picking scripture and taking it out of context) even though the people were making an incorrect assumption about Jesus (acting like they expected a prophet to act, but he was much more than that).  In a similar case of "not understanding", the peoples' expectations about their Messiah, and the inherent assumptions, were mistaken.  Many were "expecting" their Messiah to be more like King David and overthrow the Jews' enemies. The actual Messiah did something different.

Comment: @Casanova Further that point, Jamin Grey has already explained that Jesus can be a prophet as a subset of the totality of who He is.  It's not either or, it's both.  You are attempting to construct an either / or condition where there isn't one.  See also Paul (Saul of Tarsus): a tent maker AND an evangelist.  Being one does not preclude the other.